# How to call DLL exported functions with @<number> at end of function name from C

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to call functions from ntvdm.lib in Visual Studio 2019 using the Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_XP) platform toolset, with the following defined:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define i386
```

running dumpbin /exports on the LIB file I get the following output:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30037.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file ntvdm.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  _BlockWOWIdle@4
                  _CurrentMonitorTeb
                  _DBGNotifyDebugged@4
                  _DBGNotifyNewTask@8
                  _DBGNotifyRemoteThreadAddress@8
                  _DispatchInterrupts@0
                  _Dos_Flag_Addr
                  _DpmiSetIncrementalAlloc@4
                  _ExpLdt
                  _FlatAddress
                  _GetDOSAppName@4
                  _InitialVdmDbgFlags
                  _InitialVdmTibFlags
                  _IsCdRomFile@4
                  _MGetVdmPointer@12
                  _RedirectLongFileName@12
                  _RedirectShortFileName@12
                  _RegisterWOWIdle@0
                  _ResumeTimerThread@0
                  _SelectorLimit
                  _SetShadowDescriptorEntries@8
                  _ShortPathEnvVar@4
                  _Sim32pGetVDMPointer@8
                  _SoftPcEoi@8
                  _SuspendTimerThread@0
                  _VDDAllocMem@12
                  _VDDAllocateDosHandle@12
                  _VDDAssociateNtHandle@12
                  _VDDDeInstallIOHook@12
                  _VDDDeInstallMemoryHook@12
                  _VDDDeInstallUserHook@4
                  _VDDExcludeMem@12
                  _VDDFreeMem@12
                  _VDDIncludeMem@12
                  _VDDInstallIOHook@16
                  _VDDInstallMemoryHook@16
                  _VDDInstallUserHook@20
                  _VDDQueryDMA@12
                  _VDDReleaseDosHandle@8
                  _VDDReleaseIrqLine@8
                  _VDDRequestDMA@16
                  _VDDReserveIrqLine@8
                  _VDDRetrieveNtHandle@16
                  _VDDSetDMA@16
                  _VDDSimulate16@0
                  _VDDTerminateVDM@0
                  _VdmDbgAttach@0
                  _VdmGetParametersInfoError@0
                  _VdmMapFlat@12
                  _VdmParametersInfo@12
                  _VdmTraceEvent@12
                  _WOWSysErrorBox@20
                  _WaitIfIdle@0
                  _call_ica_hw_interrupt@12
                  _cmdCheckTemp@4
                  _cmdCheckTempInit@0
                  _cpu_createthread@8
                  _demClientErrorEx@12
                  _demFileDelete@4
                  _demFileFindFirst@12
                  _demFileFindNext@4
                  _demGetFileTimeByHandle_WOW@4
                  _demGetPhysicalDriveType@4
                  _demIsShortPathName@8
                  _demLFNCleanup@0
                  _demLFNGetCurrentDirectory@8
                  _demSetCurrentDirectoryGetDrive@8
                  _demWOWLFNAllocateSearchHandle@4
                  _demWOWLFNCloseSearchHandle@4
                  _demWOWLFNEntry@4
                  _demWOWLFNGetSearchHandle@4
                  _demWOWLFNInit@4
                  _fSeparateWow
                  _getAF@0
                  _getAH@0
                  _getAL@0
                  _getAX@0
                  _getBH@0
                  _getBL@0
                  _getBP@0
                  _getBX@0
                  _getCF@0
                  _getCH@0
                  _getCL@0
                  _getCS@0
                  _getCX@0
                  _getDF@0
                  _getDH@0
                  _getDI@0
                  _getDL@0
                  _getDS@0
                  _getDX@0
                  _getEAX@0
                  _getEBP@0
                  _getEBX@0
                  _getECX@0
                  _getEDI@0
                  _getEDX@0
                  _getEFLAGS@0
                  _getEIP@0
                  _getES@0
                  _getESI@0
                  _getESP@0
                  _getFS@0
                  _getGS@0
                  _getIF@0
                  _getIP@0
                  _getIntelRegistersPointer@0
                  _getMSW@0
                  _getOF@0
                  _getPF@0
                  _getSF@0
                  _getSI@0
                  _getSP@0
                  _getSS@0
                  _getZF@0
                  _host_CreateThread@24
                  _host_ExitThread@4
                  _host_com_close@4
                  _host_direct_access_error@4
                  _host_simulate@0
                  _pDeviceChain
                  _setAF@4
                  _setAH@4
                  _setAL@4
                  _setAX@4
                  _setBH@4
                  _setBL@4
                  _setBP@4
                  _setBX@4
                  _setCF@4
                  _setCH@4
                  _setCL@4
                  _setCS@4
                  _setCX@4
                  _setDF@4
                  _setDH@4
                  _setDI@4
                  _setDL@4
                  _setDS@4
                  _setDX@4
                  _setEAX@4
                  _setEBP@4
                  _setEBX@4
                  _setECX@4
                  _setEDI@4
                  _setEDX@4
                  _setEFLAGS@4
                  _setEIP@4
                  _setES@4
                  _setESI@4
                  _setESP@4
                  _setFS@4
                  _setGS@4
                  _setIF@4
                  _setIP@4
                  _setMSW@4
                  _setOF@4
                  _setPF@4
                  _setSF@4
                  _setSI@4
                  _setSP@4
                  _setSS@4
                  _setZF@4

  Summary

          BD .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           4 .idata$4
           4 .idata$5
           A .idata$6
```

The function definition I'm trying to call in VDDSVC.h is:

```
#define GetVDMPointer(Address, Size, Mode) Sim32GetVDMPointer(\
                        Address, Size, Mode)
```

However visual studio error is:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _MGetVdmPointer referenced in function _VddDispatch
```

_MGetVdmPointer is in the lib file but referenced as **_MGetVdmPointer@12**

- I reviewed the options here but couldn't determine which one might apply in my scenario https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=msvc-170
- In **Linker** -> **General** -> **Show Progress** I tried setting **/VERBOSE** although no additional information was generated in the logs
- I tried changing calling convention to "**__stdcall**" in C/C++ -> Advanced Calling Convention
- I've tried changing files from .C to .CPP although get similar error (Although the symbol looked for is a c++ mangled style name)

Comment: Are you actually passing `ntvdm.lib` to the linker as input?

Comment: Yes using #pragma comment(lib,”ntvdm.lib”) and checked with procmon it is successfully opening the lib file

Comment: This almost sounds like you are compiling a 64-bit executable. This cannot work since [NTVDM and 16-bit app support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/ntvdm-and-16-bit-app-support) is only available on 32-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: IT’s set to 32-bit (x86) This is the interface for 32-bit code to communicate to 16-bit Virtual Device Drivers , so that that the 32-bit code can retrieve the status of the DOS virtual machine state

Comment: But the documentation for these APIs seems to be removed now from MS site, although the .lib and .h are in current SDK, I’m migrating a 16-bit device driver to modern platform with lost source code that relies on this technique so trying to work out how to use it myself.

Comment: I am building on 64-bit OS though, although wouldn’t expect that should be an issue if my DLL is building at 32-bit, it will be only used on 32-bit OS

Comment: Building on a 64-bit OS is not an issue. This looks like the compiler is defaulting to `__cdecl` (see [decorated names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names)).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was calling convention needs to be modified to "**__stdcall**" in **C/C++** -> **Advanced Calling Convention**

Which I had tried, however Visual Studio 2019 project properties was defaulting to configuration for "**Release**" build and not the current build type "**Debug(Active)**" which effectively made my initial change of that setting ineffective.

As suggested in comments by IInspectable:

When changing global project properties, always make sure the "Configuration" is set to "**All Configurations**" and "**Platform**" is set to "**All Platforms**"

Comment: The age-old trap. When changing global project properties, always make sure the "Configuration" is set to *"All Configurations"* and "Platform" is set to *"All Platforms"*.